# Android JSON Null

Tags: android, mysql, json

This post request goes to a php page that connects to my database that queries whatever is in the textfield "name". The string that is appended to results is always null when I know for a fact they are not null. What am I miss?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    URI website = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "hello";
    JSONObject jArray = null;


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        website = new URI("http://fakesite.com");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
    getRequest.setURI(website);

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(website);


    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name.toString() ));
        postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = client.execute(postRequest);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        results.append(" got response");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

        results.append(result);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name.toString() ));

what is name in  name.toString(). Where are you initialising the name object?

Comment: name is the edittext that I use as my user input.  name = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

Comment: name.getText().toString(); Shouldn't you be using this to get the value in the EditText